# Can't ping a URL, but seeing that URL in Chrome Network Request Logs

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ping, redirection

I am trying to ping `alb.reddit.com`, but for some reason I get a request timed out response.

However, I am seeing chrome logs for those requests, and they are returning 200. Based off my analysis, these requests only get called when clicking on an ad on `reddit.com` and therefore going to some external link.

But even that being the case, is there any reason why a normal `ping` command would be able to give me the IP associated with this URL?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish with pinging the domain?

Comment: Disabling pings on servers is not uncommon. That `alb.reddit.com` host is most likely related to ad delivery and/or tracking from Reddit.

Answer (score 2):

In order for a ping to work, the server has to actually acknowledge the ping (aka respond to it).

A server does not have to obey ICMP (ping) requests.

Assuming that if you cannot ping a domainname or IP address, it does not exist, is the wrong assessment.

In your case, the server behind alb.reddit.com does indeed not respond to ICMP messages.

However, if we request information about the domainname itself, we get a response, which indicates that this is an existing address.

The command for this is: `nslookup -q=all alb.reddit.com 8.8.8.8`